# Send multiple fields with the same name via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

how to send multiple fields with the same name via jQuery like this:

```
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
```

jQuery:

```
   function upload() {
    $.post('example.php', { text[]: Form.text[].value },
      function(output) {
      $('#result').html(output).show();
      });
    }
```

upload.php:

```
text[$i] = $_POST['text'][$i];
```

thank you,

***EDIT: correct my question.***

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) will do the right thing and produce the appropriate form parameters for such a set of inputs.

```
$(function() {
   $('form').submit( function() {
       $.post( 'foo.php', $('[name^=bar]').serialize(), function(data) {
           alert(data);
       });
       return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: my question is how to send multiple fields with the same name via jQuery not to upload files!!

Comment: @Swell - I've updated my answer to address other types of inputs.